# Uploading image to google drive

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have one android application where you can enter your details and draw picture. Then with button click excel file is created and picture is saved and sent to desired email.

As I understand I can't insert picture to excel. So maybe it can work sending picture to Google drive and inserting link to excel file.

I don't have to worry about permissions as this is for personal use.

Problem is, I just don't understand Google documentation.

I have been on that page: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

And I have looked into that code:

```
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
    File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
        .setFields("id")
        .execute();
    System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

    POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
    Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE]
    Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]

    [JPEG_DATA]
```

But this says very little to me how to upload custom (previously created) file to Google drive?

Haven't find any articles also, only ones that are deprecated now.
Is there any place/video/article where it's explained in more detail/simpler?

Comment: "But this says very little to me how to upload custom (previously created) file to Google drive?" Well that's uploading `files/photo.jpg`, a previously-created file. I'm not sure what's missing from this example that you'd expect in order to upload a different file. Could you clarify what you've attempted in terms of modifying this example for your use case, and what happened?

Comment: @JonSkeet Most confusing part is where to find implementation for driveService as I have no idea what driveService should contain. Haven't worked with Google apis before

Comment: Okay, that's a very different problem - I suggest you start with https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java, which takes you through it step by step.